# How to add my manual creted .desktop app launcher to Frequent tab?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I create launcher icon for downloaded official ICQ client:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ICQ
Comment=Official desktop application for the ICQ messaging service
TryExec=/opt/icq/icq
Exec=/opt/icq/icq -urlcommand %u
Icon=/home/mature/.local/share/icons/icq.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;Qt;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/icq;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
```

Save it: `~/.local/share/applications/icqdesktop.desktop`

Now I can see it in my **Show Application** menu in **All** tab, but it does not want to get in **Frequent** group.

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom application frequently enough, and it will move into the Frequent group.

Frequent Applications is populated automatically with the most frequently used applications on your system. There is no way, a.f.a.i.k., that the user can control what makes it there, apart from effectively launching the application frequently.

So have some patience: after a while, and quite soon, your application will make it in there. In the mean time, pin it as a favorite on your dash for easy access.